# How can I point the location of an assembly reference?

Tags: asp.net, dll, reference, webforms, assemblies

Although I have included the proper dll as a refernce and although it builds and runs with success locally while debuging with VS when I publish the website to the server I get the following error. The relevant dll is published to the server as well but is seems that the server cannot locate the assembly. What am I doing wrong? Should I add the path of the dll in the webconfgi file?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure to check your added references in the solution explorer to see if its properties are set to "copy local" TRUE